# VS2013 Changing AppPool to classic mode in IISExpress no longer works

Tags: visual-studio-2013, iis-express

after running appcmd set app "mywebsite/" /applicationPool:"Clr4ClassicAppPool" i attempted to  re-run the web app only to find that IISExpress for the mywebsite app would no longer load in IISExpress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by locating the applicaitonhost.config file in C:\Users\myusername\Documents\IISExpress\config and updating the application pool and setting it to  Clr4IntegratedAppPool.

Hope this helps someone out there that runs into the same issue.

```
    <sites>
        <site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <site name="mywebsite" id="2">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Projects\mywebsite" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:56103:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <siteDefaults>
            <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
            <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
        </siteDefaults>
        <applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
        <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
    </sites>
```

Comment: This doesn't really fix the issue if you *need* to run in Classic mode instead of Integrated mode.